# What's the first \XeTeXglyph slot in a font, is it 0 or 1?

Tags: fonts, xetex

It's not clear whether `\XeTeXglyph0` or `\XeTeXglyph1` is the first glyph in the font. Where does the glyph count start at (0 or 1)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

XeTeX uses the regular scheme for numbering glyphs from OpenType fonts which is also used by other programs, the first glyph is `0`.

But the first glyph by definition is the `.notdef` glyph which is used as replacement if a glyph is missing. So if you actually try `\XeTeXglyph0` it will look as if you used a character the font doesn't support. The first *real* glyph is at index `1`.